# Authenticate CORS request using OpenIdConnect and Azure AD

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have Asp.Net core backend running in Azure.
HTML/JS frontend running on localhost, using CORS to communicate with backend

When both, frontend and backend are in localhost, or they are both in Azure, the authentication works -> Azure AD app is setup correctly.

Here is how I log in:

```
[Route("/api/[controller]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {        
        return Json(new AccountInfoViewModel
        {
            IsAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated,
            UserName = User.Identity.Name,
            Roles = new string[0],
            LoginUrl = Url.Action(nameof(Login), null, null, null, Request.Host.Value),
            LogoutUrl = Url.Action(nameof(Login), null, null, null, Request.Host.Value),
        });
    }

    [HttpGet("login")]
    public async Task Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = returnUrl });
    }

    [HttpGet("logoff")]
    public async Task LogOff()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    [HttpGet("endsession")]
    public async Task EndSession()
    {
        // If AAD sends a single sign-out message to the app, end the user's session, but don't redirect to AAD for sign out.
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
}
```

so from localhost, I then redirect to:

```
https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/Account/Login?returnUrl=localhost:12345
```

which triggers `Login` action and it redirects me to my Azure AD SSO page and after login, it redirects me back to localhost. However, the request to the backend is still not authenticated.

**Important**:
When I remove redirectUrl from login action, I'm redirected to the backend root instead of original origin (localhost). Any request from that origin (backend) is authenticated.

Comment: Hi @Liero, can you please share some more information? It will really help to see all the response headers of these requests. (The original ones and the redirects)

Comment: Well, with `xhr.withCredentials = true;` I've managed to get it work in Edge, see my anwer. However, it still does not work in Chrome. Edge sends 2 cookies: `ARRAfinity=... AspNetCore.Cookies=...`. Chrome sends only ARRAfinity and I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to explicitelly tell javascript to include authentication headers:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;
```

for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors#credentials-in-cross-origin-requests

EDIT: in case of chrome and opera, which implements **SameSite** attribute of cookies, you also have to setup authentication cookie like this:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(...)
         .AddCookie(option => option.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None)
         .AddOpenIdConnect(...)
```