# xhr.withCredentials = true; does not work in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, authentication, cookies, cross-domain

I have problem authenticating CORS request in Chrome.

I've Single Page Application running on localhost and webservices running in Azure. I log in using using OpenIdConnect.

When I do CORS request in EDGE to my backend like this, authentication works:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'get',
   url: buildBackendUrl("api/Account"),
   xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
});
```

however the same does not work in Chrome. When I enter the webservice url to browser manually, the request is authenticated.

I've examined request headers for CORS request and the difference is in cookies:

- Edge:  `ARRAfinity=...; AspNetCore.Cookies=...`
- Chrome: `ARRAfinity=...`

Why Chrome does not include all cookies?

EDIT: here are request catched by fiddler:

1. REDIRECT when I press login: 
   `myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/Account/login?returnUrl=http://localhost:46563/`
2. Since I'm already logged in no need to go to login page. Redirect
   `myapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc`
3. REDIRECT BACK: `localhost:46563/`
4. CORS made from Localhost:
   `myapp-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/Account`

In neither, request nr3 or 4 I don't see the cookies.

Anyway, response of request nr2 (`myapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc`) tries to sets cookies:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Expires: -1
Location: http://localhost:46563/
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Correlation.OpenIdConnect.3ifhkwCQkMuZkTgBxYiKMOSoLgTX2nIex-8aH-syh5Q=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/signin-oidc; samesite=lax
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.OpenIdConnect.Nonce.CfDJ8FG-d2csck1FsQu2pwqnsxLd4w9YWobqchk1w3xMgy7bCX_KilCuRxuj4U0bSTAL-dD_iwdEaZI6pclqlP-3f7QBuKUMS379DFiBPd_tkEkyB_IYVWzJsR1xtw-_qcS1pQL6ial_C2ywbSwRucBxUqtDPMcuFEIomNDDnklpqWUmS_5Xb_tB23Ew7b14M861pL1CtJ18uPqgu-nOgn1RygqhBhMECoQfQ7YhXN_BtfiIbdPfw00jWNfMVc5G1B-SnT_eq80_RmxQ4_JOX3ZJfiI=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/signin-oidc; samesite=lax
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Cookies=...; path=/; samesite=lax; httponly
```

Comment: Rather impossible to tell with those short snippets ... I suppose you have first of all checked whether those cookies are _set_ in Chrome to begin with?

Comment: So just to be clear, this is about the cookie set for the `localhost` domain, and you expect that to be send - when exactly, where to?

Comment: I've checked that chrome 3rd party cookies are allowed in chrome settings. I expect that I send `.AspNetCore.Cookies=...` with the request made from localhost to `myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/Account`. However I'm not 100% sure where this cookies comes from. I guess the are generated by myapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc and set to localhost

Comment: Cookies are only send with requests for the domains that they are set for. Of course a cookie set for the `localhost` domain is not send to a completely different domain, such as `myapp.azurewebsites.net` ...

Comment: I see. I've cleared chrome browser data and cookies for `localhost` are not set. But nr2 should set cookies for the `myapp.azurewebsites.net`, see the edit, right? so these cookies should be present in AJAX request to the domain, right? But they are not

Comment: Well at most the last cookie should be send to `myapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc`, because the other two are not even valid for that path. When you check the cookies set for `myapp.azurewebsites.net` after the whole thing, are they all there? If the browser did not _accept_ them, it can’t send them back either.

Comment: _“I guess the are generated by myapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc and set to localhost”_ - `myapp.azurewebsites.net` can not set cookies for `localhost` ... would be a huge security issue, if something like that was possible.

Comment: Yes, the last cookie from `myapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc` is the authentication cookie. This cookie is set for `myapp.azurewebsites.net` When I manually visit this domain, request is authenticated. Also, when I steal the cookie in fiddler and attach them to the problematic CORS call, it works

Comment: I've found out, that the `.AspNetCore.Cookies` have property SameSite=lax in chrome. When I manually create the cookies without the property, it works

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SameSite: _“SameSite prevents the browser from sending this cookie along with cross-site requests.”_ - so yeah, that seems to be “working as designed.” _“As of April 2017 the SameSite attribute is implemented in Chrome and Opera.”_ - so that explains why you did not have the problem in other browsers. Guess you will have to configure your system to set those cookies without that flag then somehow.

Comment: Do you want to create an anwser? You may include link to asp.net core 2 specific answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46485755/authenticate-cors-request-using-openidconnect-and-azure-ad

Comment: You can also write an answer yourself - considering that you found the last link, that explains what specifically needs to be changed in the configuration, that would be appropriate here I think :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theres new draft on cookie policy, called **SameSite**, currently implemented by Chrome and Opera.

Basically, cookies marked with SameSite=Strict are not sent with CORS request event if you set `xhr.withCredentials = true`;

In order to make it work, you have to disable SameSite policy on particular cookie. In case of ASP.NET Core 2.0 authetication cookie it was:

```
services.AddAuthentication(...)
    .AddCookie(option => option.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None)
    .AddOpenIdConnect(...)
```